# Call django context_processor without request as normal function

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a model and when I create a new record it must send a signal to the context_processor to display a popup in the Django admin site telling the user that there is a new record in that model that has been created.

Comment: I think you do not understand what is django context processor ? Context processor allow you to send some variables in any template without add them to context when you call the render function. Your question seems to need an API with ajax call or use websocket ? If you are sure, you need to call context processor, please give more informations

Comment: the case is that the mobile app sends an alert to the server and this alert is saved in a model called  `Alert` and what I want is when a new record is inserted into the database I need a popup show in the admin to tell the admin that a user X sends an alert. So in your opinion what is the best solution to do this cycle?

Comment: IMO, simple solution is your mobile app retrieve every XX seconds on your server list of new alert and when a new alert happen, your mobile app can display a popup. Other solution is two open a bidirectionnal connection between server and mobile with websocket for example where you server can directly send to mobile information like new alert... Second solution is much harder than first solution. For second solution, you can check django-channels: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/